# Div won't push the content down

Tags: css, jquery, html

I have a div which I'm populating with ajax. The problem is that the div, when elements are added to it, goes beyond the page. The content ends up being hidden and I can't scroll to see the content. How do I get the div to push the page down?

Here's the code I'm using to populate the div:

```
function draw(){

    var fName,memType,price,gTotal=0;

    var tbl = '<table class="table table-striped table-condensed optOutTable" width="100%"><tbody>';

    for (var i=0, tot=cart.length; i < tot; i++) {

        fName = cart[i][2];
        memType = cart[i][3];
        price = cart[i][4];
        gTotal = gTotal+parseFloat(price,10);

        tbl+= '<tr><td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" onclick="removeFromCart(\'\',this); return false;">x</a></td><td nowrap>'+fName+'</td><td width="100%">'+memType+'</td><td>$'+parseFloat(price,10).toFixed(2)+'</td></tr>';      

    }

        tbl+= '</tbody><tfoot><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>$'+gTotal.toFixed(2)+'</td></tr></tfoot></table>';

        $('#cart').html(tbl);

}
```

Here's what the html looks like:

```
<div>
<div id="cart">Your cart is empty.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any CSS on the div?  Is `overflow` being set to `hidden`?

Comment: Happen to have the css that goes with this?

Comment: hey guys... there's actually no css attached to that div element. Also, just tried setting the overflow to hidden and that didn't work

Comment: @Damien what Adrian meant was make sure you DON'T have overflow hidden on the div. Use firebug or other dev tools to see the cart container and see if there is any unwanted styles that's creating this behaviour. I highly doubt the js is doing it

Comment: `#cartContainer` has `overflow:hidden`

Comment: sorry... just put that in... give it another shot, you'll get the same results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <div id="cart" style="overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll; max-height:500px;">Your cart is empty.</div>
</div>
```

You can change the `max-height` whatever value you want!

Comment: i see what you're doing there. i was gonna do this as a last resort. I really wanted the content to push the page down especially since ultimately, under the cart will be a form.

Comment: So put your div in between the content whatever content you want to push down. Also make the div `display:none` when page loads and then when you call `draw()` method after generating the content make that visible and place your dynamic cart items. That way it will push your content down! Is it your requirements or something else? I think it is done same [here](https://bgcpros.worldsecuresystems.com/members/register-multiple-members) also.

Comment: let me create a dummy form and see what this looks like irl. i'll get back to you soon

Comment: putting it between the form and content worked! Dude... can't believe it, what a headache. Thanks a lot man, don't know why it didn't work the other way. Thanks for everything! Can you edit your answer so i can check it and give you credit.

Comment: i will, just edit it cause what's there right now didn't actually fix it. Thanks a million!